# Detecting programmatic change in checkbox state

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, onclick, onchange

I have a checkbox:

```
<input id="abcd" name="abcd" type="checkbox" onclick="doSomething(this, 'otherparams');">
```

Now, I have some other code, that could do the following:

```
document.getElementByID("abcd").checked=true;
```

I want `doSomething` to fire even when I change the state of the checkbox programmatically. (Am ready to use anyone of `onchange/onclick` in the checkbox input)

Here is what I am trying: http://jsfiddle.net/hfovh2xm/6/

To give some context:  Its a large piece of code with multiple interacting modules (a module that I do not want to edit could set the checkbox value, I would like to detect that change in my module).

Comment: You have to trigger the event yourself. Here you can simply call the `doSomething ` function instead. Note that you have `onclick` attribute not `onchange`!

Comment: how about `$("#abcd").trigger("click")` ? or simply call `doSomething($("#abcd")[0], 'otherparams');`

Comment: @Vohuman I tried even with onchange. Still does not work as in the fiddle. Of course last resort is to fire it myself, but its a large piece of code with multiple interacting modules (a module that I do not want to edit could set the checkbox value, I would like to detect that in my module).